# A question on direct product of groups

Tags: group-theory

A is a finite Abelian group and p is a prime.

```
  A^p = {a^p ; a is in A} and 

  A_p = {a ; a^p =1}
```

Now it is clear that A/A_p is isomorphic to A^p. But how to prove that A/A^p is isomorphic to A_p?  Clearly they have same order and it is told to show that both of them are elementary abelian. But how?

Comment: Just note that, in both $A_p$ and $A/A^p$, every element has order dividing $p$. Since they are abelian, they must then be elementary abelian.

Comment: I totally understand it now

Answer (score 1):

They aren't isomorphic in general if $A$ is infinite. For finite Abelian groups, you can express the group as a direct sum of cyclic groups.
As $A\mapsto A^p$ and $A\mapsto A_p$ are preserved under direct sums, then
all you have to do is to prove the result for finite cyclic groups.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by the maps are preserved under direct sums